# How to add entry for primary and secondary intermediate cert in ssl apache

Tags: apache-2.2

I have 1 intermediate certificate with name intermediate.crt But my providing is saying to add 2 certificates primary and secondary.

But how to add it in ssl configuration file. Currently I have added only secondary certificate as below

**SSLCertificateChainFile "/usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/intermediate.crt"**

But now as my ssl provider is saying to add 2 certificates then what entry i have to do in my ssl.conf file. Or I can also use bundle.pem file which contains both the certificates in 1 file. Let me know how to add bundle.pem file also.

Answer (score 0):

Just cat the intermediate certificates together and pass just the one file in the config. :)